# JSON Vs JSONP Vs CORS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jsonp, cors

Can anyone help me in understanding the differences between JSON, JSONP & CORS, from an asp.net MVC perspective?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

JSON is a data format, while JSON-P and CORS are mechanisms/protocols for making cross-domain requests for data.

**JSON** is a format for representing data. It was first defined in JavaScript, but has grown to become a de facto way for APIs to represent data. Most languages have libraries for parsing JSON. You can learn more about this format here: http://json.org/. Here's an example JSON object:

```
{
  "key": "value"
}
```

**JSON-P** is a mechanism for loading data in JavaScript. It bypasses the browser's [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) in order to load data from another domain. It does this by embedding a JavaScript `script` on the page. This script calls out to the remote domain, which returns data wrapped in a JavaScript function. When this function returns to the browser, it is executed, which allows the calling code to access the data.

Note that while the name has the word "JSON", JSON-P doesn't necessarily have to work with JSON. For example, it could return a string or any other valid JavaScript data type back to the user.

Note that while JSON-P works in every browser, it is a hack to get around the browser's same-origin policy, and it has some limitations. For example, it can only issue a GET request, and the caller doesn't have access to the response headers. Since it is custom to browsers and JavaScript, JSON-P is not really appropriate for accessing data from other languages, like server-side Python.

You can learn more about JSON-P here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

**CORS** is a standardized mechanism for making cross-domain requests. It is supported in [most modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=cors). The client uses the standard XmlHttpRequest object to make a CORS request. Upon receiving the request, the server decides whether the cross-domain request is allowed. If it is allowed, the server issues special headers that allows the response to be passed on to the client.

You can find the CORS spec here: http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/
You can learn more about how to use CORS here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

All these technologies are independent of ASP.NET MVC. If you'd like to use these technologies, you should first ask yourself "Do I need to access data across domains?" If the answer is "yes", you should then ask "What browsers/platforms do I need to support?" If your answer is "most modern browsers", then you should consider implementing CORS. Otherwise you should use JSON-P

Answer (score 3):

CORS is a specification which has nothing to do with JSONP beyond making it obsolete in newer browsers. It enables cross-domain requests using ordinary XMLHttpRequest calls.

[Here's an overview](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/) of how it works and how to use it. It can be used in Firefox 3.5+, Safari 4+, Chrome 3+, Internet Explorer 8+, and [anything else using one of the same engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing).

for details go on reading

> http://json-p.org/

Comment: Yups you should and don't forget to accept as answer. Regards